# Being able to use a method of comparable items to sort while inserting them into a List at the same time

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, comparable

I wasnt sure how to properly title this.
Heres the problem im trying to solve, the prompt is:

**In this problem, you will create a method that takes all of the items in an array of Comparable items and places them in a List.  It will be able to store the items in any class that implements the List interface, so you will use both an ArrayList and the SingleLinkedList2 class from above.**

**First, write a method that has the following heading:**

```
private static void sort(Comparable[] items, List aList)
```

**The sort method should use the clear method from the List class to remove any entries before beginning its sort algorithm.**

**It then should process the items in the array in the order in which they appear in the array and place them in the list one-at-a-time.**

**Do NOT sort them in the array prior to inserting them into the list.
When adding an into the list, that item must be placed at the correct position in the list so that the list is always sorted.
If an item is already in the list, do not enter it again (avoid duplicates)**

This is what I have so far:

```
 private static void sort(Comparable[] items, List aList)
{
        aList.clear();
        aList.add(0, items[0]);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if(items[count].compareTo(aList.get(i)) < 0)
            {
                aList.add(i - 1, items[i]);
            }
            else if(items[count].compareTo(aList.get(i - 1)) > 0)
            {
                aList.add(i);
            }
            count++;
            count -= 1;
        }
}
```

So, im stuck. If you can see above, I think what I am doing is comparing the items to whats already in the List(prior to the loop I added the first element to the list. and initialized and declared a counter). So we want to probably be able to refer back to the array and the new list as we sort it.

Comment: `count++; count -= 1;` better leave it alone.

Comment: Your outer loop is going though the array items one by one: so far so good.  Now you need an _inner_ loop to search though `aList` to find the right spot to insert each item.  The item will go either 1) at the first slot where you find an items that compares greater, or 2) at the end (if you never found a greater one)